# Amazon Cloud Search API compatibility with Solr API

Tags: solr, solrnet, amazon-cloudsearch

With [Amazon's Cloud Search being powered by Solr](http://lucidworks.com/blog/amazons-cloudsearch-gets-solr-powered/), I have certain questions before we proceed. May be someone who has experience with both can guide us.

1. How compatible Amazon's Cloud Search's API with Solr API ? Are they same, or radically different?
2. Is it compatible with queries being performed via Solrnet?
3. How different it is from Solr?

The reason we're asking is, we need to migrate one application from Solr to Amazon Cloud Search and before we proceed we need some idea on how does this work?

I checked with Amazon Cloud Search documentation, but unable to find any details on this particular thing!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/26gAjZVMSA0/4XRHN0KOTYYJ

Answer (score 3):

Amazon cloudsearch is based on solr, so conceptually they work same way, but amazon has written its own wrapper on top of solr api. Answers to the questions in same order below:

1. Amazon cloud search has two endpoints, one for search and other for indexing documents. Provides with multiple ways of indexing like S3 documents, JSON, XML etc.
2. Amazon cloudsearch has four different query parsers, if you place queries using Lucence as query parser, query syntax and functionality is same.
3. The only difference I observed functionally is cloudsearch doesn't support hierarchy in fields data, it only provides with text and literal datatypes and their arrays for multiple values.

There are migration tools available like http://www.8kmiles.com/blog/apache-solr-to-amazon-cloudsearch-migration-tool/ which support migration from solr to cloudsearch.